# Android sms app that incremets every time it receives an sms

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have developed an app that can receive sms's, but actually what I wanted is to receive an sms from a certain number then the number of the sms's received increments by one everytime an sms is received

This is in my manifest

```
<receiver android:name = "SmsReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and this is what I have in my SmsReceiver class that extends BroadcastReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");

    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0; n<messages.length; n++){
        sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])messages[n]);
    }
    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        DOH_Home.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: " + msg.getOriginatingAddress() + "\n" + "Message:" + msg.getMessageBody() + "\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: firstly I don't want the app to receive all the sms's I get on my phone, I just want it to get the one's I will specify. Then I don't really want it to display the sms, I just want it to keep a record of how many sms's I get from that number. I know I haven't done much but I am new at this and this was just becoming too complex for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    String number = "YOUR_SEARCHED_NUMBER";
    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        String sender = msg.getOriginatingAddress() ;
        if (sender != null && sender.equals(number)){
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            int count = pref.getInt("COUNT", 0);
            count++;
            pref.edit().putInt("COUNT", count).commit();
        }
     }
```